# Consequences of direct comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Check whether the statement is true:

If $\left(n^{2} a_{n}\right)$ is convergent sequence, then there is a subsequence $\left(x_{n_k}\right)$ of $x_{n}=\frac{\sin (n)}{n}$ such that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_{n_k} a_{k}$ is convergent

I tried the direct comparison test with $b_k=\frac{1}{k^2}$, but confused with $n_k$ and $k$?

Any role for Bolzanno- Weierstrass theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(n^2 a_n)$ converges, there is $C > 0$ such that
$$|a_n| \le \frac{C}{n^2}$$
for all sufficiently large $n$. Therefore,
$$\sum_n |a_n| < +\infty.$$
Moreover,
$$\frac{|\sin(n) a_n|}{n} \le |a_n|, $$
and so
$$\sum_n x_na_n <+\infty.$$
It seems to work without taking a subsequence of $x_n$..